# Black color filled in remaining space Listview xamarin-UWP

Tags: uwp, xamarin.forms, uwp-xaml

Am having a weird issue. this is happening only in Xamarin forms- UWP. Am using Listview inside Listview. when i click on each list child list will be shown. Also i have set a fixed height for child list so that it can be scrolled. Now on checking even it has more items  black color is filled at the bottom. How can i fixed this.

[image: Descr]

XAML For List:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyProducts" 
          IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}"
          RefreshCommand="{Binding GetAllProducts,Mode=TwoWay}"
          IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
          HasUnevenRows="True" 
          BackgroundColor="White"
          ItemSelected="CategorySelected"
          SeparatorVisibility="None"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MyProductsList}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#e6e6e6" Margin="0,2,0,2">
                    <StackLayout Margin="1" BackgroundColor="White">
                        <Grid Padding="0,10,0,0">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Text="Product Category" YAlign="Center"  Margin="10,0,0,0"  Style="{DynamicResource LabelLightStyle}"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding Model.ProductCategoryName}" Style="{DynamicResource LabelRedStyle}" YAlign="Center"  Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                            <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" IsVisible="{Binding IconDown}" Source="ArrowDown.png" HeightRequest="15" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="0,0,5,0" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                            <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" IsVisible="{Binding IconUp}" Source="ArrowUp.png" HeightRequest="15" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="0,0,5,0" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                            <ListView Grid.Row="2"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                      IsVisible="{Binding ListVisibility}"
                                      SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                                      SeparatorColor="#e6e6e6"
                                      ItemSelected="ProductSelected"
                                      HeightRequest="220"
                                      BackgroundColor="#f2f2f2" 
                                      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Model.Products}">
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ViewCell>
                                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#e6e6e6">
                                                <StackLayout Margin="0,0,0,1" BackgroundColor="#f2f2f2">
                                                    <Grid Padding="0,10,0,10">
                                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding MachineModel, StringFormat='Machine Model Number : {0}'}" YAlign="Center"  Margin="10,0,0,0"  Style="{DynamicResource LabelStyle}"/>
                                                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding CreatedDate, StringFormat='Date {0}'}" Style="{DynamicResource LabelTinyStyle}" YAlign="Center"  Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                                        <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Source="ArrowRight.png" HeightRequest="15" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="0,0,10,0" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </ViewCell>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListView>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Where is your XAML? Can you post it?

Comment: This is working fine in IOS and android.This wierd issue is happening only in UWP. Please find the xaml used https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MpbGpZxfu6dsynLGGwJ_eYAHW1pnt37hHFVs1P6MrDM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Why do you have 2 `StackLayout` in `DataTemplate` one with `BackgroundColor="#e6e6e6"`, and another with `BackgroundColor="White"`?

Comment: @avk-naidu Its for showing the border. I had to do some tweaks to get better view in UWP. But that is not the issue. Issue happens only when i try to give Height for Listview. I have given it because i have long list and i just need a scrolling effect for drop down within limited height for list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by writing custom ViewCell and by making use of native datatemplate. Now there is no black cells on fast scrolling. I am posting my answer so that someone may find it useful.

For eg: If you have a list of names to be displayed follow:

First add custom viewcell as follows

```
    public class CustomViewCell : ViewCell
   {
    public static readonly BindableProperty NameProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("Name", typeof(string), typeof(CustomViewCell), "");

    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
    }

   }
```

Now add the ListView in XAML as follows:

```
        <ListView 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <custom:CustomViewCell  Name="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Then you have to write the DateTemplate style in App.xaml of UWP project as follows:

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomTemplate">
        <Grid Padding="10">
            <TextBlock  Foreground="#333333" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Finally write a CustomRenderer to replace the native viewcell to our our ListView.

```
public class CustomViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
{
public override Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate GetTemplate(Cell cell)
{
    return App.Current.Resources["CustomTemplate"] as Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate;
}
}
```

Now list works perfectly without any black cell rendering issue.

Comment: After following these steps the items are not showing in the Listview, am I missing something here?